# How can I use Bigbluebutton on laravel for create meeting, join meeting

Tags: bigbluebutton

Using composer require bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php in my laravel project, used bigbluebutton, also set for BBB_SERVER_BASE_URL, BBB_SECURITY_SALT, but not able to create meetings.

```
$meetingParams = new CreateMeetingParameters($request->meetingId, 
     $request->meetingName);
$meetingParams->setDuration(40);
$meetingParams->setModeratorPassword('supersecretpwd');

$meetingParams = new CreateMeetingParameters($request->meetingId, $request->meetingName);
$meetingParams->setDuration(40);
$meetingParams->setModeratorPassword('supersecretpwd');
```

I need proper code to create meetings in laravel, using bigbluebutton.

Answer (score 1):

use this package for laravel [bigbluebutton](https://github.com/joisarjignesh/bigbluebutton)

```
\Bigbluebutton::create([
    'meetingID' => 'tamku',
    'meetingName' => 'test meeting',
    'attendeePW' => 'attendee',
    'moderatorPW' => 'moderator'
]);
```